# Footer and Slider not displaying in Prestashop

Tags: themes, prestashop, e-commerce

After deleting all the dummy products from my website having prestashop, sliderand footer got hidden.

Comment: how did you delete all those products? in database or back-office?

Comment: through backoffice admin